# LibreOffice calc conversion formula to string

Tags: formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How to change formula, e.g. =2+2 or =CONCATENATE("hello","world") to const string value in cell?

Answer (score 0):

Just in Edit Mode press F9 and Enter.